# Summing values from treeview if row is empty Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to sum values from treeview column no matter if one of the rows is empty, also I want to delete that row when the Sum button is pressed. I wrote a code but I always get this error:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk

myApp = Tk()
myApp.title(" Program ")                         

TotalEntry=Entry(myApp, width=18)
TotalEntry.grid(row=0,column=1, sticky="e", pady=5)

NewTree= ttk.Treeview(myApp, height=7)

NewTree['show'] = 'headings'
NewTree["columns"]=("1")

NewTree.column("1", width=80, anchor="center")

NewTree.heading("1", text="ID")

item = NewTree.insert("", "end", values=(2))
item = NewTree.insert("", "end", values=(""))
item = NewTree.insert("", "end", values=(6))

NewTree.grid(row=0,column=0)

def SumAllCosts():

    for i in NewTree.get_children():
        a = NewTree.item(i,"values")[0]

        if len(a)==0:
            NewTree.delete(i)

    SumPreCosts=0.0
    for child in NewTree.get_children():
        PreCost=round(float(NewTree.item(child,"values")[0]),2)
        SumPreCosts += PreCost

        TotalEntry.delete(0,"end")
        TotalEntry.insert(0,round(SumPreCosts,2))


Sum=Button(myApp,text=" Sum ",command=SumAllCosts)
Sum.grid(row=0,column=2, sticky="w",pady=5)


myApp.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print `type(NewTree.item(i, "values"))` and `repr(NewTree.item(i, "values"))`, you can see that this returns

```
<class 'tuple'> ('2',)
<class 'str'> ''
<class 'tuple'> ('6',)
```

As you can see, for the 2 and 6 entry, this returns a tuple so you can do `NewTree.item(i, "values")[0]` to get the first value. However, the empty item is returned as an empty string, so `NewTree.item(i, "values")[0]` gives the error you describe.

You can change that part of the code to check if `NewTree.item(i, "values")` is not empty:

```
for i in NewTree.get_children():
    if not NewTree.item(i, "values"):
        NewTree.delete(i)
```